# Adding a path to login.conf in Bash / FreeBSD

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, path, freebsd, pip

Due to the fact that freebsd pkg repos (binary) do not come with support for lame mp3, and I don't want to complicate things by having a dual dependency tree, I'm attempting a workaround by installing ffmpeg with pip.

**Install:** I've installed `ffmpeg` and `youtube-dl` using `pip install youtube-dl ffmpeg --user`

**Finding the paths**: `find . -name ff\*´` returns that `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` packages are installed in my `./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` directory and there are two other noteworthy files: `.../python3.6/site-packages/postprocessor/ffmpeg.py` and `.../python3.6/site-packages/postprocessor/__pycache__/ffmpeg.cpython36.pyc`.

my youtube-dl is in ´~/.local/bin/´ and runs without any problems if i type out it's entire path, but my ffmpeg is not found. I read that editing my paths would solve this issue.

**Edit Paths** with `sudo vim /etc/login.conf/` go to the section that says `default:\ ...path=`
and add my `youtube-dl` path `/usr/home/.local/bin/` as well as my ffmpeg path `/usr/home/.local/lib/site-packages/`

When I run youtube-dl ffmpeg is not found. When I try to execute youtube-dl without it's fullpathname it returns command not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it is easier to edit `~/.bashrc` and set `PATH` there.

Comment: alright, i'll try that

Comment: i didn't think to check my $PATH with `env` first. I see now that what I set in `login.conf` does not correspond with the output of this command. My guess is that this is probably because my original installation was with CSH. I understand there is a simple command `set` that i can use to easily reset this. However I would like to know *where* my shell is pulling this from. All of the commands that I know of only show the *value* of $PATH, and not where it is located.

Comment: this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154971/236541
is an interesting solution, but neither of the solutions mentioned show me all of the locations of PATH that I know about. Still not clear where the definitive PATH bash uses is being pulled from.

Answer (score 1):

#### It is not clear where the definitive PATH bash uses is being pulled from

You need to work through the list of `bash` startup files looking for commands that set the `PATH` variable.

> **Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.)**
>
> If you have ever put something in a file like .bashrc and had it not
>   work, or are confused by why there are so many different files —
>   .bashrc, .bash_profile, .bash_login, .profile etc. — and what they do,
>   this is for you.
>
> The issue is that Bash sources from a different file based on what
>   kind of shell it thinks it is in. For an “interactive non-login
>   shell”, it reads .bashrc, but for an “interactive login shell” it
>   reads from the first of .bash_profile, .bash_login and .profile
>   (only). There is no sane reason why this should be so; it’s just
>   historical. Follows in more detail.
>
> For Bash, they work as follows. Read down the appropriate column.
>   Executes A, then B, then C, etc. The B1, B2, B3 means it executes only
>   the first of those files found.
>
> ```
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> |                |Interactive|Interactive|Script|
> |                |login      |non-login  |      |
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> |/etc/profile    |   A       |           |      |
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> |/etc/bash.bashrc|           |    A      |      |
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> |~/.bashrc       |           |    B      |      |
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> |~/.bash_profile |   B1      |           |      |
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> |~/.bash_login   |   B2      |           |      |
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> |~/.profile      |   B3      |           |      |
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> |BASH_ENV        |           |           |  A   |
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> |                |           |           |      |
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> |                |           |           |      |
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> |~/.bash_logout  |    C      |           |      |
> +----------------+-----------+-----------+------+
> ```

Source [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)